# Multi-column nonclustered index not being used

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have nonclustered index, it has 4 four fields in the index key, When I am searching the records using first field it gives index seek, But when I am using remaining columns, it does index scan. Multiple column on non clustered index will not be useful?

Comment: If you have a telephone directory listing everyone's names in alphabetical order, `surname, firstname` style, how useful is that book for finding everyone with the first name `John`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I see some of the missing index recommendation in execution plan to have multiple key columns in clustered index.  Missing Index Details from SQLQuery2.sql
The Query Processor estimates that implementing the following index could improve the query cost by 97.9186%.
*/

/*

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dsp].[AssetSubscriptionHistory] ([SUBSCRIPTION_ID],[STATUS])
INCLUDE ([USER_TYPE_ID],[ASSET_ID],[APP_ID],[UCID],[DEALER_CUSTOMER_NO],[DEALER_CODE],)
GO
*/

Comment: Post your query, the DDL for the tables involved, some sample data and the relevant parts of the plan if you want a specific answer.  https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/